# how can i play the video of html5 player when i select a menu item?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

http://www.netraserve.com/meltest-offline

this is the link of website . When i click on "Giv it a Shot " then the video in "Giv it a Shot" should play automatically .

The code which i am using is :

```
    <script>
$('#GoToTeam').click(function(e) {              
            var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
        myVideo.play(); 
}
</script>
```

but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

It should be `vid.play()` not `myVideo.play()`

```
$('#GoToTeam').click(function(e) {              
            var vid = $("#myVideo"); 
            vid.get(0).play(); 
}
```

Comment: <script>
$('#GoToTeam').click(function(e) {    
   var vid = $("#myVideo"); 
            vid.get(0).play();  
}
</script>

Comment: What does that means?